# How can I make a percentage circle like google?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a percentage circle like on this picture:

[image]

I've tried to use this here but I'm not very happy. I'm not able to change the progress of the circle and all in all I'm not sure if this is the best idea I've head:

```css
circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 326px;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    stroke: #000000;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
 <svg>
     <circle r="52" cx="54" cy="54"></circle>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345858/html-how-do-i-generate-a-progress-bar-circle-with-a-percentage-in-and-set-the/49345972

Comment: @Kurisu This is a way too complex for what I want to do. Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Increase the `stroke-dasharray` property so a single dash is enough to make it all the way around the circle and then some. Then animate the `stroke-dashoffset` property.

Bonus: Add a `<span>` to hold the percentage and animate the `content` attribute by adding a percentage value to display for each percentage of the animation.

```css
circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 330;
  stroke-dashoffset: 330;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: #000000;
  fill: none;
  transform: rotate(-86deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  animation-name: drawCircle;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 70px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#percent::after {
  content: "0";
  animation-name: writePercent;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes drawCircle {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 330;
  }
  30% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  }
}

@keyframes writePercent {
  0% {
    content: "0";
  }
  1% {
    content: "1";
  }
  2% {
    content: "2";
  }
  3% {
    content: "3";
  }
  4% {
    content: "4";
  }
  5% {
    content: "5";
  }
  6% {
    content: "6";
  }
  7% {
    content: "7";
  }
  8% {
    content: "8";
  }
  9% {
    content: "9";
  }
  10% {
    content: "10";
  }
  11% {
    content: "11";
  }
  12% {
    content: "12";
  }
  13% {
    content: "13";
  }
  14% {
    content: "14";
  }
  15% {
    content: "15";
  }
  16% {
    content: "16";
  }
  17% {
    content: "17";
  }
  18% {
    content: "18";
  }
  19% {
    content: "19";
  }
  20% {
    content: "20";
  }
  21% {
    content: "21";
  }
  22% {
    content: "22";
  }
  23% {
    content: "23";
  }
  24% {
    content: "24";
  }
  25% {
    content: "25";
  }
  26% {
    content: "26";
  }
  27% {
    content: "27";
  }
  28% {
    content: "28";
  }
  29% {
    content: "29";
  }
  30% {
    content: "30";
  }
  100% {
    content: "30";
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
     <circle r="52" cx="150" cy="54"></circle>
 </svg>
<div><span id="percent"></span>%</div>
```

Comment: Ohh those CSS keyframes... seems like a perfect time to not waste any more keystrokes and simply go for JS or SMIL ;) nice answer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No doubt JS is the way to go. But since OP only tagged the question with HTML & CSS, and didn't include any JS code in the example, I figured I'd offer a CSS solution.