# calculate percentage in progress circle

Tags: html, jquery, svg

I would like to generate a progress circle dynamically (live) without clicking the button render

Example:

- add 10 to input in ingredient 1, add 10 to input in ingredient 2, add 10 to input in ingredient 3. Total is 30 circle should render without clicking the render button
- uncheck any of the ingredient checkboxes total calculates all inputs values. Total circle should render without clicking the render button

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/worldwildweb/mcjs9275/

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 
 
  $(function() {
  $(".tags").on('input', function() {

    var calculated_total_sum = $(this).find(".ingredient").map(function() {
      const chck = $(this).is(":checked")
      const val = $(this).closest("div").find(".txtCal").val()
      return chck ? +val : 0;
    }).get().reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    $("#percent").val(calculated_total_sum);
    if ($("#percent").text() > 1000) {
    $("#percent").css('color', 'red');
  }    
  else{
    $("#percent").css('color', 'green');
  }
  });
});
// ingrédients allergènes
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).hide().val('0');
  
  
  var list = $('.results > li').hide();
  //For each one checked
  $('input:checked').each(function() {
    list.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).show();
  });
}).find('input:checkbox').change();  

$(".tags").on('input', '.txtCal', function () {
     var calculated_total_sum = 0;
   
     $(".tags .txtCal").each(function () {
         var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
         if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
            calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
            }                  
          });
            $("#percent").val(calculated_total_sum);



            
     });

     var svg ;

function drawProgress(end){ 
d3.select("svg").remove() 
  if(svg){
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();
  
}
var wrapper = document.getElementById('radialprogress');
var start = 0;
 
var colours = {
  fill: '#FF0000',
  track: '#555555',
  text: '#00C0FF',
  stroke: '#FFFFFF',
}

var radius = 80;
var border = 12;
var strokeSpacing = 4;
var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
var boxSize = radius * 2;
var count = end;
var progress = start;
var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;

//Define the circle
var circle = d3.svg.arc()
  .startAngle(0)
  .innerRadius(radius)
  .outerRadius(radius - border);

//setup SVG wrapper
svg = d3.select(wrapper)
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', boxSize)
  .attr('height', boxSize);

  
// ADD Group container
var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');

//Setup track
var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
track.append('path')
  .attr('fill', colours.track)
  .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
  .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
  .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));

//Add colour fill
var value = track.append('path')
  .attr('fill', colours.fill)
  .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
  .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px');

//Add text value
var numberText = track.append('text')
  .attr('fill', colours.text)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', '.5rem'); 

  //update position of endAngle
  value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * end));
  //update text value
  numberText.text(formatText(end));
  
}

$('#submitClick').click(function(){
  var val = parseInt($('#percent').val());
   drawProgress(val/100)
})
 
drawProgress(10/100)

});
```

```html
    <div class="tags">
      <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-1" class="ingredient"> ingredient 1 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal'  /><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-2" class="ingredient"> ingredient 2 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-3" class="ingredient"> ingredient 3 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
      </div>
      <span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b>
      <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345858/html-how-do-i-generate-a-progress-bar-circle-with-a-percentage-in-and-set-the -->
      <label for="percent">Type a percent!</label>
<input id="percent" name="percent" value=10>
<button id='submitClick' name='submitButton' >Render</button>


<div id="radialprogress"></div>
    </div>


        <ul class="results">
             <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-3">Alpha isomethylionone</li>
             <li class="ingredient-1">Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)</li>
             <li class="ingredient-1">Amylcinnamyl alcohol</li>
             <li class="ingredient-1">Anisyl alcohol</li>
             <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">Benzyl alcohol</li>
             <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Benzyl benzoate</li>
             <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl cinnamate</li>
             <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl salicylate</li>
             <li class="ingredient-2">Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)</li>
             <li class="ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Cinnamal</li>
             <li class="ingredient-3">Cinnamyl alcohol</li>
             <li class="ingredient-3">Citral</li>
             <li class="ingredient-3">Citronellol</li>
             <li class="ingredient-3">Coumarin</li>
        </ul>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the progress circle redraw when the values are changed simply call the `drawProgress()` function within the `input` event handler.

Also note that there's a couple of other improvements you can make to the code:

- remove nested document.ready
- delegate is deprecated, use on instead
- `$('#percent').text()` should be `$('#percent').val()`, and I would assume `1000` in the condition on that line should be `100` instead.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#submitClick').click(function() {
    var val = parseInt($('#percent').val());
    drawProgress(val / 100);
  }).trigger('click');
  
  $(".tags").on('input', function() {
    // needlessly using 2 loops here, amended
    //var calculated_total_sum = $(this).find(".ingredient:checked").map((i, el) => parseFloat($(el).closest("div").find(".txtCal").val())).get().reduce((a, b) => a + b) || 0;   
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;
    $(this).find('div:has(.ingredient:checked) .txtCal').each((i, el) => calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(el.value));   
    
    $("#percent")
      .val(calculated_total_sum)
      .css('color', parseFloat($("#percent").val()) > 1000 ? 'red' : 'green');
      
    drawProgress(calculated_total_sum / 100);
  });

  // ingrédients allergènes
  $('div.tags').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).hide().val('0');
    var list = $('.results > li').hide();
    
    $('input:checked').each(function() {
      list.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
      $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).show();
    });
  }).find('input:checkbox').change();

  $(".tags").on('input', '.txtCal', function() {
    var calculated_total_sum = 0;
    $(".tags .txtCal").each(function() {
      var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
      if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
        calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
      }
    });
    $("#percent").val(calculated_total_sum);
  });

  var svg;

  function drawProgress(end) {
    d3.select("svg").remove()
    if (svg) {
      svg.selectAll("*").remove();
    }
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('radialprogress');
    var start = 0;

    var colours = {
      fill: '#FF0000',
      track: '#555555',
      text: '#00C0FF',
      stroke: '#FFFFFF',
    }

    var radius = 80;
    var border = 12;
    var strokeSpacing = 4;
    var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
    var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
    var boxSize = radius * 2;
    var count = end;
    var progress = start;
    var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;

    //Define the circle
    var circle = d3.svg.arc()
      .startAngle(0)
      .innerRadius(radius)
      .outerRadius(radius - border);

    //setup SVG wrapper
    svg = d3.select(wrapper)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', boxSize)
      .attr('height', boxSize);


    // ADD Group container
    var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');

    //Setup track
    var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
    track.append('path')
      .attr('fill', colours.track)
      .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
      .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
      .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));

    //Add colour fill
    var value = track.append('path')
      .attr('fill', colours.fill)
      .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
      .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px');

    //Add text value
    var numberText = track.append('text')
      .attr('fill', colours.text)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('dy', '.5rem');

    //update position of endAngle
    value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * end));
    //update text value
    numberText.text(formatText(end));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-1" class="ingredient"> ingredient 1 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-2" class="ingredient"> ingredient 2 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-3" class="ingredient"> ingredient 3 </label><br><input type="text" class='txtCal' /><br>
  </div>
  <span><b>TOTAL  :</b></span><b><span id="total_sum_value"></span></b>
  <label for="percent">Type a percent!</label>
  <input id="percent" name="percent" value="0">
  <button id='submitClick' name='submitButton'>Render</button>
  <div id="radialprogress"></div>
</div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-3">Alpha isomethylionone</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amylcinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Anisyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">Benzyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Benzyl benzoate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl cinnamate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl salicylate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Cinnamal</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Cinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citral</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citronellol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Coumarin</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for your 3rd point : $('#percent').text() should be $('#percent').val(), and I would assume 1000 in the condition on that line should be 100 instead.

the idea is that when % is > 100 the circle becomes red otherwise =< 100 circle is green

Comment: That was my assumption, which is why I made the change I described.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easier to create that circle with a `<path>`,
and then use `pathLength="100"` and `stroke-dasharray="30 70"` to set 30% progress.

**No need for jQuery or D3 libraries**

A modern Custom Element (supported in all modern browsers) makes for a re-usable HTML Element

```html
 <svg-progress-circle percent="30"></svg-progress-circle>
 <svg-progress-circle percent="20" color="blue"></svg-progress-circle>
 <svg-progress-circle percent="80" color="gold"></svg-progress-circle>
```

[image]

See the slider `oninput`, set the value with:

```js
    document.getElementById("Slider1").percent = <PERCENTAGE>;
```

```html
<style>
  svg { width: 150px; background: teal; }
  svg-progress-circle[percent="100"] path { stroke: green; }
</style>

<svg-progress-circle percent="30"></svg-progress-circle>
<svg-progress-circle percent="20" color="blue"></svg-progress-circle>
<svg-progress-circle percent="80" color="gold"></svg-progress-circle>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-progress-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let d = 'M5,30a25,25 0 1,1 50,0a25,25 0 1,1 -50,0'; // circle
      this.innerHTML = `<input min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30" oninput="this.parentNode.percent=this.value" type="range"/><br>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <path stroke-dasharray="10 2"   stroke-dashoffset="-19" 
        pathlength="120" d="${d}" fill="grey" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="5"/>
  <path stroke-dasharray="30 70" stroke-dashoffset="-25" 
        pathlength="100" d="${d}" fill="none" 
        stroke="${this.getAttribute("color")||"red"}" stroke-width="5"/>
  <text x="50%" y="57%" text-anchor="middle">30%</text></svg></span>`;
      this.style.display='inline-block';
      this.percent = this.getAttribute("percent");
    }
    set percent(val = 0) {
      this.setAttribute("percent", val);
      let dash = val + " " + (100 - val);
      this.querySelector("path+path").setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', dash);
      this.querySelector("text").innerHTML = val + "%";
      this.querySelector("input").value = val;
    }
  })
</script>
```