# Set svg progress bar percentage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I watched a YouTube tutorial and managed to make a circular progress bar. Attached is my code. Issue I face is I don't know how to dynamically set progress bar percentage using JavaScript according to the result calculated from values. eg I want progress bar to go to 25% if answer of calculation is 25% which is percent variable.

```js
var percent = revenue/investment;
document.getElementById("circ").style.strokeDashoffset = percent;
```

```css
.box .percent svg  circle:nth-child(1)
{
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
    stroke:#f3f3f3;
}
.box .percent svg  circle:nth-child(2)
{
    stroke-dashoffset:calc(440 - (440*10) / 100);
    stroke:#03a9f4 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="percent">
        <svg>
            <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
            <circle id="circ" cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
        </svg>
        <div class="number">
            <h2 id="percent"></h2><span>%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculate percentage in progress circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205662/calculate-percentage-in-progress-circle)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pure SVG (only SVG attributes) version. The pathLength is 100 and the first value in the dasharray is therefore a number between 0 and 100. The "starting point" for the path is at 12 o'clock after I have rotated the circle.

```js
let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
document.forms.form01.range.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  c1.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${value} 100`);
  t1.textContent = `${value}%`;
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input name="range" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
</form>
<svg width="200" xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <circle id="c1" cx="25" cy="25" r="24" stroke-width="2"
    stroke="darkorange" fill="none" transform="rotate(-90 25 25)"
    stroke-dasharray="50 100" pathLength="100" />
  <text id="t1" x="25" y="25" dominant-baseline="middle"
    text-anchor="middle" font-size="10">50%</text>
</svg>
```

And a more CSS'sy example:

```js
let c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
let t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
document.forms.form01.range.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  c1.style.strokeDasharray = `${value} 100`;
  t1.textContent = `${value}%`;
});
```

```css
circle#c1 {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke: darkorange;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 50 100;
}

text#t1 {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input name="range" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
</form>
<svg width="200" xmlns="http//www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <circle id="c1" cx="25" cy="25" r="24"
    transform="rotate(-90 25 25)" pathLength="100" />
  <text id="t1" x="25" y="25">50%</text>
</svg>
```