# how can i fill the of the bottle with color using clipPath

Tags: html, css

I have an image of a bottle and try fill this bottle of some color

I found the fill coordinates, but my background inside of bottle doesn't filled

```css
.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#tubeLiquid {
  background-color: #74ccf4;
  clip-path: polygon(45% 19%, 41% 22%, 41% 29%, 41% 36%, 41% 43%, 41% 50%, 41% 57%, 41% 63%, 41% 70%, 41% 77%, 41% 83%, 41% 90%, 43% 93%, 50% 92%, 56% 93%, 60% 88%, 59% 81%, 60% 75%, 60% 68%, 60% 61%, 59% 55%, 59% 48%, 59% 42%, 59% 35%, 59% 29%, 58% 23%, 54% 19%);
}

#bottleMask{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  clip-path: polygon(45% 19%, 41% 22%, 41% 29%, 41% 36%, 41% 43%, 41% 50%, 41% 57%, 41% 63%, 41% 70%, 41% 77%, 41% 83%, 41% 90%, 43% 93%, 50% 92%, 56% 93%, 60% 88%, 59% 81%, 60% 75%, 60% 68%, 60% 61%, 59% 55%, 59% 48%, 59% 42%, 59% 35%, 59% 29%, 58% 23%, 54% 19%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <image
      width="300"
      clip-path="url(#bottleMask)"
      xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/Mhfwtxp/image-removebg-preview-1.png"
    ></image>
    <defs>
      <mask id="bottleMask"></mask>
    </defs>
    <g id="maskedLiquid" mask="url(#bottleMask)">
      <path id="tubeLiquid" fill="#74ccf4"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution I found is this i didnt fill the whole bottle but you just need to change some of the coordinates in polygons i dont have that knowledge about shapes and polygons.

```
<style>
.item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#tubeLiquid {
  background-color: #74ccf4;
  clip-path: polygon(45% 19%, 41% 22%, 41% 29%, 41% 36%, 41% 43%, 41% 50%, 41% 57%, 41% 63%, 41% 70%, 41% 77%, 41% 83%, 41% 90%, 43% 93%, 50% 92%, 56% 93%, 60% 88%, 59% 81%, 60% 75%, 60% 68%, 60% 61%, 59% 55%, 59% 48%, 59% 42%, 59% 35%, 59% 29%, 58% 23%, 54% 19%);
}

#bottleMask{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  clip-path: polygon(45% 19%, 41% 22%, 41% 29%, 41% 36%, 41% 43%, 41% 50%, 41% 57%, 41% 63%, 41% 70%, 41% 77%, 41% 83%, 41% 90%, 43% 93%, 50% 92%, 56% 93%, 60% 88%, 59% 81%, 60% 75%, 60% 68%, 60% 61%, 59% 55%, 59% 48%, 59% 42%, 59% 35%, 59% 29%, 58% 23%, 54% 19%);
}</style>

<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <defs>
      <mask id="bottleMask" fill="white">
        <path d="M0,0h300v300H0V0z M89,68h122v147H89V68z" />
      </mask>
      <clipPath id="liquidClip">
        <path d="M89,68h122v147H89V68z" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <image width="300" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/Mhfwtxp/image-removebg-preview-1.png" />
    <path id="tubeLiquid" fill="#74ccf4" d="M0,0h300v300H0V0z" clip-path="url(#liquidClip)" mask="url(#bottleMask)" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an additional `<mask>`.
Due to the shape of the bottle, you could use a rounded `<rect>` as clip-path:

```js
waterLevel.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let value = +e.currentTarget.value
  tubeLiquid.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${value} 100`)
})
```

```css
svg {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<h3>Draw clip-path</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <image width="300" href="https://i.ibb.co/Mhfwtxp/image-removebg-preview-1.png" />
    <!-- test clip path -->
    <rect x="115" y="55" width="69" height="235" rx="20" ry="20" fill="red" />
  </svg>

<h3>Draw liquid fill</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <image width="300" href="https://i.ibb.co/Mhfwtxp/image-removebg-preview-1.png" />
    <line x1="149.5" y1="290" x2="149.5" y2="50" stroke="green" stroke-width="70" />
  </svg>

<h3>Apply clip path</h3>
<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" id="waterLevel" name="water-level" /></p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <clipPath id="clip">
          <rect x="115" y="55" width="69" height="235" rx="20" ry="20" fill="red" />
    </clipPath>
    <image width="300" href="https://i.ibb.co/Mhfwtxp/image-removebg-preview-1.png" />
    <line id="tubeLiquid" clip-path="url(#clip)" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="100 100" x1="149.5" y1="290" x2="149.5" y2="50" stroke="#74ccf4" stroke-width="80" />
  </svg>
```

Draw your clip-path and fill-scale/progress bar shapes first – without clipping anything – to find the right coordinates and dimensions.

Then you can apply, the clip-path.
I've used a `<line>` element for the "tubeLiquid" element as it allows us to set the `pathLength` attribute to 100.

We can easily change the current fill value by updating the `stroke-dasharray` attribute:

```
// show 100 %
stroke-dasharray="100 100"

// show 50 %
stroke-dasharray="50 100"
```

You'll find a lot of examples on SO using this method for all kinds of **dynamic gauges/progress bars or animated pie charts** like ["Set svg progress bar percentage in javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72676042/set-svg-progress-bar-percentage-in-javascript)